# Bad file association in WMI repository

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, file-association, wmi

Windows 7 machine, and as far as I know, the only oddness about the system is what I mention below.

I deal with a whole lot of text files that have no extension, so a while back, I associated files with no extension with Notepad++ x64.  Well, I needed the functionality of plugins that aren't compatible with x64 and ended up removing it.

I've since tried issuing new commands to associate files with no extension with the 32 bit version installed under the x86 path, but in spite of that, any time I try to double-click the file, it's pointing to the regular "program files" path.  I've searched the entire registry several times and cannot find mention of the path that doesn't exist, and if I make a second copy of N++ under the regular program files path it works just fine, but I'd love to only use one copy.

After additional work, I think I might've found the source of the problem.  It appears to be a bad entry in my WMI Repository (OBJECTS.DATA file in ..\WBEM\Repository).  Unfortunately, I've done exactly zero with that and everything I'm reading from MS tells me to only try and rebuild it as an absolute last resort, and since this is just a bad file association, I'm fairly reluctant to do so.

Is there any way to repair a file association in the WMI repository?

Comment: The basic idea would be to [use this](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html) tutorial but create your own .reg file to restore/delete the association you made to all files without a file extension.

Comment: I've deleted the key for . under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (which is what is what I did to associate it in the first place), but that's not working.  I'm starting to think there is another place where such associations are stored.

Comment: I assume you have searched for the `../Program Files/N+ Installation directory here` in your registry?

Comment: I hope you are not literally searching for "N+" because that isn't the name of the executable.  You are searching name of the executable, right?

Comment: Well, I think I've found where it is, but I have zero idea how to fix it.  It appears to be stuck somewhere in the WMI repository, and I'm not terribly comfy messing with that at this point.  I'm looking for ways to repair it without rebuilding it.

Comment: Care to update your question with specifics?

Comment: I think the WMI repository is a red herring, as far as I know it isn't related in any way with file association of Windows Explorer, at least not in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting in the association problem, as I have put in the comments the WMI is a red herring, WMI stands for [Windows Management Instrumentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation#Purpose_of_WMI) and its an API for getting information about the system, it allows querying the information in a SQL style, for example I have used it for [getting information about running processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394599(v=vs.85).aspx). Regarding the [WMI Repository](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository/):

> The WMI Repository “%windir%System32\Wbem\Repository” is the database
>   that stores meta-information and definitions for WMI classes; in some cases the repository also stores static class data as well.

So I can't see a way that your problem could be related to the WMI repository because is not used for file association nor other Explorer configuration, maybe there is some information about Notepad++ in the repository but it's not related with this.

Regarding your problem, the "standard" way of associating a program to files without extension is using the `.` (dot) extension under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, there are two variations, the "old" way:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.]
@="Notepad++Test"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++Test]
@="Notepad++ Test"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++Test\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" %1"
```

and the "new" way introduced in Windows XP (or maybe in Windows 2000, I'm not sure):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\OpenWithProgids]
"Notepad++Test"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++Test]
@="Notepad++ Test"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++Test\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" %1"
```

(`Notepad++Test` is how I called the key that used in my tests, that key could have any name depending on who created the key and how)

Check what values do you have there, you could also check `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.\OpenWithProgids` which is a per-user list of extensions and their associated programs that Explorer populates automatically (I'm think that this key has a lower priority that the other one but I'm not sure).

If you don't have the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.` key created or if it has the correct values maybe you are using a non standard way of associating files, perhaps using a third-party program that is misconfigured.

Comment: Alas, I've not only specifically checked the keys in question, but I've searched my entire registry for the text in question and it's not in there.  The reason I think it's the WMI repository is because I've searched my entire disk for the path it's looking for, and it's only found in two places:

1. The WMI repository
2. Superfetch

Outside of that, the reason I think it's the WMI repository is because the problem remains when Superfetch is disabled.  

I suppose it could be in something that isn't File Locator Pro can't find, but if that's the case, then I'm stuck even worse.

Comment: As I stated maybe there is information about Notepad in the repository but AFAIK it can't be related with Explorer config, is on a different level in the SO architecture. Maybe you could find what is going on using [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), this program intercepts and logs all registry and filesystem activity, the problem is that it catch *all*, so maybe you need to dig quite a lot even when using filters. If you are interested in this I'll update the answer with the basics steps and blog entries from the author about its use.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a configuration issue with my Windows Explorer replacement (Directory Opus).  I'd configured its 'Open unregistered file types in text viewer if they appear to be plain text' setting to use the 64 bit version of the app.

Translation: Total PEBKAC issue.  Ugh!